How do I deregister my EC2 instance from my ELB target group without draining the container?
We have an EC2 instance that's having some issues inside the docker container it's running and we'd like to disable traffic going to that EC2 instance so we can connect to it and examine the docker container running on it. We have a problem though where when we deregister the container to stop the traffic, it will start draining because connection draining is on, which terminates the ECS task and the docker container along with it, then our auto-scaling group brings up a new task and re-registers to the ELB target group. We want to cut the traffic from the application load balancer we are using, but I can't find anything that says how to deregister without draining, lots of AWS docs I've read so far are out-of-date from the UI so I'm kind of stumped.
I looked at a few different things, including this stand-by mode, but it seems no matter what, the container will drain, as I'm pretty sure based on the application load balancer that connection draining is enabled.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-enter-exit-standby.html
Is there any way to just cut the traffic, leave the EC2 as-is without draining the container? We need to prevent any more user-traffic from going to the bad instance without the docker container going down.

According to AWS documentation, "If your instances are part of an Auto Scaling group and connection draining is enabled for your load balancer, Auto Scaling waits for the in-flight requests to complete, or for the maximum timeout to expire, before terminating instances due to a scaling event or health check replacement." (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/config-conn-drain.html)
Therefore, we likely need a longer maximum timeout, because disabling connection draining would terminate current connections immediately. However, maximum timeout has an upper limit of 3600 seconds (60 minutes). (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/target-group-health-checks.html)
An alternative strategy is to get our instance to register as 'unhealthy' because "Each load balancer node routes requests only to the healthy targets in the enabled Availability Zones for the load balancer." (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/target-group-health-checks.html) Implementation varies according to our health check rules. The important settings for this strategy are:

target_health_state.unhealthy.connection_termination.enabled - if set to false, you never drop a connection. Not Recommended
target_health_state.unhealthy.draining_interval_seconds - determines how long connections remain before terminating them. The range is 0-360000 seconds. The default value is 0 seconds. (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elbv2/modify-target-group-attributes.html)

